# can't create an issue through Redmine API

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to call the API on our Redmine instance  (v 4.2.4.stable), and facing some issues despite following the documentation. I am especially interested in creating issues (https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues).

This is what I am doing :

```
POST /issues.json
Content-Type: application/json
X-Redmine-API-Key: xxxx


{
  "issue": {
    "subject": "Subject VF",
    "project_id": 444,
    "tracker_id": 7,
    "status_id": 10,
    "description": "Desc VF"
  }
}
```

but I get a 422 response, with body :

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Project cannot be blank",
        "Tracker cannot be blank",
        "Status cannot be blank"
    ]
}
```

I had initially tried without "subject" in the payload, and was getting the additional "Subject cannot be blank" error. So at least I know that "subject" field is correct.

but why are the other fields seen as blank by the server ? the user has access to the project, and the tracker and status exist, so I really don't understand why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was that the tracker needed to be **linked** to the project first (in the admin UI). The fact that it existed was not enough.

Once this is done, then it works.